# Using OR on Inner Join

Tags: sql

I am trying to join Table A on Table B. The issue is that in Table A the join value can be in column 1,2,3,4,5 or any combination of those fields. The value is a name in the format of LastName, FirstName.
What I need is to check each field to see if it contains the value, stop after the first match and move on to the next record. If no match in any of the five fields, then that record is ignored. How can I change my code to accomplish this? (My current query returns a row for every OR condition that is true.)

```
DECLARE
@StartDate AS Datetime
SET @StartDate = '2023-01-01'


SELECT TA.*
FROM TableA AS TA
INNER JOIN
TableB AS TB ON  TB.Field1 IN (TA.Field1) OR
                 TB.Field1 IN (TA.Field2) OR
                 TB.Field1 IN (TA.Field3) OR
                 TB.Field1 IN (TA.Field4) OR
                 TB.Field1 IN (TA.Field5)

WHERE  TA.ExtractDate >= @StartDate

ORDER BY TA.ExtractDate DESC

--DROP TABLE #Manager
```

Current results:
[image]

Expected Results:
[image]

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and improve your question as explained

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible results, as mentioned above. Looks like a simple recursive CTE but without sample data, it's impossible to provide a good answer.